# accounting for possible empty parameter in RavenDB query

Tags: ravendb

I have a query that has a parameter that may or may not be empty. If it's empty, then I would like all results returned, if it's not empty, then the search should include that search term.  The only way I can get it working is using an if statement, but is there a way to get it working in one query statement?

Here's what I have so far:

```
           IList<FixturesIndex.Match> matches;

            if (input.TeamId != "")
            {
                matches = documentSession
                    .Query<FixturesIndex.Match, FixturesIndex>()
                    .Search(x => x.ParticpantOneTeamId, input.TeamId)
                    .Search(x => x.ParticpantTwoTeamId, input.TeamId)
                    .Where(x => x.CommunityId == input.RavenId)
                    .ProjectFromIndexFieldsInto<FixturesIndex.Match>()
                    .ToList()
                    .Take(10)
                    .ToList();
            }
            else
            {
                 matches = documentSession
                .Query<FixturesIndex.Match, FixturesIndex>()
                .Where(x => x.CommunityId == input.RavenId)
                .ProjectFromIndexFieldsInto<FixturesIndex.Match>()
                .ToList()
                .Take(10)
                .ToList();

            }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think is possible with the .Search.

If the problem is code duplication you could use the if only to add the .Search to the query:

```
        IList<FixturesIndex.Match> matches;
        var query = documentSession.Query<FixturesIndex.Match, FixturesIndex>();

        if (input.TeamId != "")
        {
            query = query
                .Search(x => x.ParticpantOneTeamId, input.TeamId)
                .Search(x => x.ParticpantTwoTeamId, input.TeamId);
        }

         query = query
            .Where(x => x.CommunityId == input.RavenId)
            .Take(10)
            .ProjectFromIndexFieldsInto<FixturesIndex.Match>();                
         matches = query.ToList();
```

Note that the query is executed when you call .ToList(), in your version the first .ToList() retrieve "all" records from the db and after that you take only 10 records.

Comment: That's a great workaround, thanks!  Also good to note my performance degrading ToList.